# Objective-C getter to SWIFT equivalent

Tags: swift, getter, uicollectionviewlayout

I have the following getter:

```
-(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)verticalFlowViewLayout {
 if (!_verticalFlowViewLayout) {
 _verticalFlowViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init;  
[_verticalFlowViewLayout setItemSize:DeviceIsPad()self.iPadCollectionItemPortraitSize :self.iPhoneCollectionItemPortraitSize];
[_verticalFlowViewLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:MIN_LINE_SPACING];
[_verticalFlowViewLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
}
return _verticalFlowViewLayout;
}
```

And I want to transform it to SWIFT 2. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
lazy var verticalFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    verticalFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    //other configuration here
}()
```

Comment: Correct, but with this method you cannot use other class types. (i.e the frame size of a collection view outlet). However, I used get{} with a temporary variable  (let tempFlow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()) for this time being and it seems working...